# how to show two customers in the one table row MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

with asp.net ,i have used ListView to show tow customers per row:

```
  <asp:ListView ID="CustListView" runat="server" 
                                GroupItemCount="2"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse;border-color:#111111;width:100%;" >

                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" >
                                                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                   </table>
                               </LayoutTemplate>

                               <GroupTemplate>
                               <tr>
                                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                               </tr>
                               </GroupTemplate>

                               <ItemTemplate>
                                  <%#Eval("Customer.Name")%>

                               <ItemTemplate> 
               </ListView/>
```

How can i do that in mvc 2.any links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC the first thing is to forget about any WebForms controls that you might have used. Things like `ListView` are irrelevant. In ASP.NET MVC you work with Models, Controllers and Views. So you could start by defining a view model:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which your controller should fill:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new[]
    {
        new CustomerViewModel { Name = "John" },
        new CustomerViewModel { Name = "Peter" },
        new CustomerViewModel { Name = "Mary" },
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally you have a view which is strongly typed to `CustomerViewModel[]` in which you could generate a table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Name) %></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Darin.Does this show two customers/table row.Just one

Comment: @user594166, there will be as many rows as there are objects in the view model (which is an array of customers in this example).

Comment: @user594166, well in this case you could adapt your view model so that it no longer represents an array of customers but an array of another view model which contains the 2 customers.